# How do i make the 7 segment blink with a changing number/hexa using Verilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga

```
begin
            counter <= counter + 1; 
            led <= ( counter == 20'b00000000000000000000 ) ? ~led: led;    
end
```

It's just blinking on and off with all lighted up/off (number 8) now. How do I make it so that it blinks a certain no./letter?

Comment: https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/tutorials/tutorial-your-first-vhdl-program-part1.html

Answer (score -1):

What board are you using? That is very important here. Typically if you have a 7 segment display with multiple digits, there will be some control signal that enables certain digits and another signal to control which segments are on for an enabled digit.

Here is the case for the [Basys3](https://reference.digilentinc.com/basys3/refmanual#basic_io) (a popular starting board): There are 4 digits and 4 anode signals that enable a given digit when driven low (set to 0). If you want to illuminate different segments on each digit, you cycle through all of the digits anywhere from 60 times a second to 1000 times a second. There are 8 segment signals, including a decimal point signal, that illuminate a segment in the activated digit when driven low.

Example: To make an '8' appear on the first digit, you set the first anode signal to 0 and all the segments (except decimal point) to 0.